# How to exclude unchanged columns sql table c#

Tags: c#, sql

How do I exclude some columns from being modified using SQL Update statement? Here is the code, but I want to update only the columns that user enter data in. Using Windows Forms in C#.
EXAMPLE, I want to update only the Class using the Windows Form

```
var query="update UserRegistration Set FirstName= @FirstName, LastName=@LastName, Class=@Class, [Password]=@Password WHERE UserID=@UserID";
           
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtuserid.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtfirstname.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtlastname.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtclass.Text;
```

Comment: What is the problem if your update command tries to update every column? By the way, you are using AddWithValue incorrectly, the second parameter is the Value, not the Type.

Comment: Steve, If I only supply data to Class, it wipes the rest of the columns

Comment: If you only want to update one field, then only have one field in your `query`.   This is why frameworks like EF were created, to help with these problems that 'simpler' methods give.

Comment: You could do either one of 2 things. 1) Retrieve all the data and let the user modify it (instead of supplying new values). Then unchanged data is updated to itself. 2) Create a statement and add parameters only for fields where there is a supplied value.

Comment: @Neil assume you dont know which field user wants to update....

Comment: If the unchanged fields are passed to the query as null (DBNull.Value) then you can do: `ISNULL(@theparam, <column name>)`. This will retain the original value of the column if the parameter value is null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function. Or an analog in other RDBMS.

Change SQL query like this

```sql
update UserRegistration set
    FirstName = isnull(@FirstName, FirstName),
    LastName = isnull(@LastName, LastName),
    Class = isnull(@Class, Class),
    [Password] = isnull(@Password, [Password])
where UserID = @UserID;
```

Also change C# code like this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =
   txtfirstname.Text == "" ? null : txtfirstname.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically create a SQL command using only the the field names that are populated.  (This is a brute force method, and could be simplified by using a dictionary, but shown like this to make it simpler to understand)

```
var fieldList = new List<string>();

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtuserid.Text;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtfirstname.Text))
{
    fieldList.Add("FirstName=@FirstName");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtfirstname.Text;
}
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtlastname.Text))
{
    fieldList.Add("LastName=@LastName");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtlastname.Text;
}
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtclass.Text))
{
    fieldList.Add("Class=@Class");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtclass.Text;
}
var fields = string.Join(',', fieldNames);
var query=$"update UserRegistration SET {fields} WHERE UserId=@UserID";
```

This means that if you only want to update the first name, the query string becomes:

```
update UserRegistration SET FirstName=@FirstName WHERE UserId=@UserId
```